Homeless Benefits for Carte de Sejour Holder?
I hold a 10-year CDS and have recently lost everything due to being abandoned by my husband and his girlfriend taking all assets. I don't have a home and barely have €100 in my bank account. I am American and my husband is a dual US/EU citizen, which is what my CDS approval was based on. While my CDS allows me to work, my poor use of the language makes it difficult, but I am hoping to move somewhere I can find work as an English speaker. I could settle anywhere.
My question is, would I qualify for any type of housing or support to get back on my feet? I am 64 years old.
Thanks for any answers or links to where I might find the answers.

Sorry for your difficult situation. Have you worked in France, registered and paid into French social security since living there?

You may be eligible for the RSA, you could approach an assistant(e) sociale or perhaps a non-profit for help in figuring out what you are entitled to.

Look for a  Centre Communal d'Action Sociale (CCAS) in the town where you live, this is an entry point for many social benefits conselling.

Have you lived in France for more than 5 years?  If you have, then you should have acquired a "right of permanent residence" that isn't conditioned on not becoming an "unreasonable burden" on the French social support system.  I suspect that this would make any applications for support somewhat simpler.  The acquisition is automatic; you don't need to have applied for a different card.
